# What is the purpose difference between README and vignette in R package?

Tags: r, documentation, readme, vignette

I have an `R` package on GitHub that I am about to submit to CRAN. Up to now, the package has had an extensive README.md document that shows:

- examples of package core functions execution,
- examples of package demo execution,
- some benchmark results.

**For the purposes of GitHub users**, I thought that putting these to README.md is more appealing than vignette as it shows up when a user views the package's repo.

When I am at the point of **moving the package to CRAN**, I would like to have pretty much the same content as currently in README.md available in a form of a vignette.

Question: is it a correct way of acting to make an almost 1-1 copy of README.md into a vignette, keep both, update GitHub repo to have this vignette as well, and then submit as such to CRAN? Or: it would pose a duplication that should not take place? (then how should I proceed?)

Comment: I'd propose an alternative - use `library(pkgdown)` to create a website for you package. It builds the site from both your README and your vignette and hosts it on github pages. For example, take my `mapdeck` library - [here is the github readme](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck#mapdeck), and here is the [`pkgdown site`](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/index.html), where the vignette is now the "getting started" page

Comment: Well, not reallty as it does not help the _user of the package who wants local resources_.  An external website requires connectivity.  If you read _Writing R Extensions_ carefully enough to get the _spirit_ of the document I feel you would agree that external resources, as common as they may be with some groups of developers, are what R Core first described.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint about `pkgdown `! I did not know about it, and I find it useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think that is not uncommmon.  You

- have a README.md at GitHub as the 'public face' of the (source) package repo
- want a package summary for which a vignette may serve well
- may even end up with a package webite or summary

and the *same* markdown text might as well serve in all three instances.

In any event there is no rule against it.  Also, in case you did not know, this would have been a good question for the dedicated and focused `r-package-devel` mailing list concerned with packaging.

Comment: That is a wonderful answer! Hint about `r-package-devel` much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome -- feel free to accept the answer. I am also one of the founders/admins of that list and of the people who may approve your first post (b/c spam) after which you're free to post more :)